# Query works in Sql but returns empty datatable

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

**Edit**

I'm so confused, now I changed this if statement:

```
 If Data.Rows.Count > 0 Then
 'Do all Voucher things in here
else
txtVoucher.text = "Sorry, Invalid Voucher"
end if
```

To display the query from the voucher checking function by outputting it as one of Voucher's string properties, like this:

```
else txtvoucher.text = Voucher.voucherName end if
```

And everything works fine! If I change it back to an error message... the datatable returns no rows. I haven't changed anything else about the code, just what goes to the textbox if the row count is 0. Shouldn't the row count be the same regardless of what I send to the textbox afterward?

**End Edit**

I am making a basic Online Voucher function for a webpage and am having issues with the voucher checking query.

I have this query, which checks the string entered into a textbox against the SQL table for a match.

```vb
Public Shared Function CheckForVoucher(ByVal strVoucherName As String) As DataTable
    Dim connect As New SqlConnection

    Dim Data As New DataTable    'Connection works, finds number of Vouchers in DB that match either code or ID. ID to be used for randomly generated vouchers.

    connect.ConnectionString = "SERVER = SERVER-SQL01; Trusted_Connection=yes; DATABASE=PCSQL"
    connect.Open()

    Dim query As String
    Dim search As String
    search = strVoucherName
    If search.Length >= 20 Then
        query = "SELECT * from PCSQL.dbo.VOUCHER_DETAILS WHERE vID='" + search + "' "
    Else
        query = "SELECT * from PCSQL.dbo.VOUCHER_DETAILS WHERE voucherName='" + search + "' "
    End If

    Dim command = New SqlDataAdapter(query, connect)
    command.Fill(Data)
    connect.Close()

    Return Data
End Function
```

The query works fine in SQL Manager, I can replace the keyword search with any of the voucher names I have in the list and it returns the correct result, same goes if I replace the search keyword in vb.net and force the query to check for a specific voucher no matter what is entered in the textbox (e.g. TestVoucher2).

I currently have the page set to check for results as below.

```vb
Protected Sub lbVoucherCheck_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lbVoucherCheck.Click

    'Voucher checking code to go here

    Dim Data As DataTable = Voucher.CheckForVoucher(txtVoucher.Text)
    If Data.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        Dim row As DataRow
        row = Data.Rows(0)

        'Set voucher properties in Voucher.vb using datarow result.
        Voucher.VoucherID = row.Item("vID").ToString().Trim()
        Voucher.VoucherName = row.Item("voucherName").ToString().Trim()
        Voucher.ExpiryDate = row.Item("ExpiryDate")
        Voucher.ValidUses = row.Item("ValidUses")
        Voucher.CurrentUses = row.Item("CurrentUses")
        Voucher.DiscountType = row.Item("DiscountType").ToString().Trim()
        Voucher.AppliesTo = row.Item("AppliesTo").ToString().Trim()
        Voucher.NumberOf = row.Item("NumberOf").ToString().Trim()
        Voucher.Amount = row.Item("Amount")
        Voucher.noOfItems = row.Item("NoOfItems")
        Voucher.Category = row.Item("Category").ToString().Trim()
        Voucher.FreebieID = row.Item("FreebieID").ToString().Trim()
        Voucher.DiscountAmount = row.Item("DiscountAmount")

        'lbVoucherCheck.Text = Data.ToString()


        'Step one: Check for Expiry Date
        Dim count As Int32
        count = 0
        Dim expiry As DateTime = Voucher.ExpiryDate
        Dim today As DateTime = Date.Today()
        count = ((expiry - today).Days)
        If count <= -1 Then
            txtVoucher.Text = "Voucher expired"
        Else
            txtVoucher.Text = "Expires in " + count.ToString() + " days."
        End If
    Else
        txtVoucher.Text = Data.rows.count
    End If
End Sub
```

When I run the query based off `txtVoucher.Text` input it returns "0", indicating that it hasn't found anything. But If I rig the query with a voucher name it returns the correct expiry result.

I have a strong feeling that it's not getting the right information from `txtVoucher.text` to my `Voucher.CheckForVoucher(txtVoucher.text)` function.

Comment: Debug it to see what you get as `query` at the end and run that to see if you get any result.

Comment: Sounds stupid but VS Studio's debugger doesn't work on this site. Everytime I try it I get errors about session state, can't access SQL servers and other weird. I didn't create the site, I've just been brought in to try and update it, but it wasn't designed in an "easy-to-fix" way.

Comment: If the debugger is not working, return the content of `query`

Comment: I'm beginning to hate this compnay's website... having changed nothing... it now works. I can't even step through and see what's happening and when... I give up. Thanks for helping.

Comment: What are the datatypes for `vID and voucherName`? I ask this because it matters and in your above function you have `'` for both where clauses... You shouldnt use `+` for string concatenation either use the `&`. Also make sure to dispose of your command/connection objects; its best to wrap them in a `Using` statement.

Comment: vID is a GUID, and voucherName is string/varchar(15) in SQL. Just for future reference, is there a functional difference between + and & or is it just convention?

Comment: Theres a difference...  + is a mathmatical operator, the concatination function of the + confuses that standard process. While "Hello" + number may work number + "Hello" may not.

Comment: did you check if there might be an id that has length lesser than 20 that was searched and you query for voucherName or the the other way around?

Comment: 8 comments and nobody cares about little booby tables?

Comment: @Zohar Peled, I care.... But I've only just arrived at this question. :-)